# Taking photo from camera by C and win32 api

Tags: c, winapi, camera, photo, take

I would to get a still image (in jpg format) from any type of cameras plugged to my computer (USB and Serial) and then save it on my hard disk, so what the code you recommend me to write while I use C programming language and Win32 api, finally I would to tell you that I work on Microsoft VC++ 2008 on Windows XP sp3 and I know that the solution of my problem related to WIA library or Microsoft STI library but I don't have any idea on how to use it or how to write code via them, so please I would a clear answer with clear codes cause I am beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow really isn't a magic code generator or personal tutor but rather a place to which you can turn when you get stuck in your code.

That said, luck has it that Microsoft provides a tutorial on how to do this:

[WIA Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It assumes you can follow C code, but if you can't already do that maybe you should start with something easier :)

Comment: I have this tutorial in the MSDN library which is installed on my pc but it is not so helpful however thank you my friend and if you know a simple clear tutorial else the one of Microsoft please tell me about it. thanks

Comment: my friend, I don't ask for a full code. I just want to know the general idea and which functions can help me or simply links to a good clear tutorials on "taking still image from cameras" subject